# Stopping the naked domain redirecting to www

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

i recently migrated my application to AWS and setup a cname for www.domain.com and a redirect for the domain.com to redirect to www.domain.com.

The problem is, an external service was using a path on the naked domain.com (something like domain.com/external/service/) But with the redirect all HTTP POST data is being dropped with the redirect and i cant change the url that the external service is calling.

To fix this, i have setup my naked domain on route53 to point to my elastic load balancer where my app is located. I set up an A record pointed at my elastic load balancer using an alias.

Its been two days now and my naked domain still redirects to www. and therefore the external service is down. Any ideas on what i could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am taking a long shot - there are different possible problems:

1. You are forwarding naked domain via A record to ELB, but your EC2 instace (say Apache) is still doing a redirect (not DNS, but http 301) back to www.
2. Check the DNS TTL. If the TTL is too large (say 48 hrs), then it takes that time. You need to wait longer.
3. Is Route53 fully managing your DNS? One possibility is that, somebody else like Godaddy is still doing the DNS for you - so nobody is contacting Route53 for the change to reflect.

Comment: it turns out the TTL was set at 48 hours which when i posted this i was 90 mins short!

Comment: Oh! ok. I missed this possibility. Edited the above answer for the benefit of new readers.